# MYSQL UPDATE SET on the Same Column but with multiple WHERE Clauses

Tags: mysql

With MYSQL I'm using this query:

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY
SET Category_ID = 10
WHERE Category_ID = 2
```

Thats fine but I'd like to ad 15+ more `SET/WHERE` to it like:

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY
SET Category_ID = 9  WHERE Category_ID = 3
SET Category_ID = 12 WHERE Category_ID = 4
SET Category_ID = 11 WHERE Category_ID = 5
.....
```

How would I add to this?

EDIT:

As Per Hunters Suggestion:

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY
    SET Category_ID = CASE Category_ID
        WHEN 2 THEN 10 
        WHEN 3 THEN 9
        WHEN 4 THEN 12
        WHEN 5 THEN 11
    END
WHERE Category_ID IN (2,3,4,5)
```

This works Great! Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY
    SET Category_ID = CASE Category_ID
        WHEN 2 THEN 10 
        WHEN 3 THEN 9
        WHEN 4 THEN 12
        WHEN 5 THEN 11
    END
WHERE Category_ID IN (2,3,4,5)
```

Alternatively, as Simon suggested, you could do this to save from entering the values twice:

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY
    SET Category_ID = CASE Category_ID
        WHEN 2 THEN 10 
        WHEN 3 THEN 9
        WHEN 4 THEN 12
        WHEN 5 THEN 11
        ELSE Category_ID
    END
```

Source: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/

Comment: Deleted my comment as tried this and worked, nice :)  As a note, you could add "ELSE Category_ID" before "END" if you didn't want to include the WHERE

Comment: Thanks. A good point; it would save from entering the columns twice.

Comment: With the `WHERE` clause, you're pretty much guaranteed to be able to utilize an index on Category_ID, also with [safe-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates) enabled, you must enter a `WHERE` clause with an `UPDATE`, so `ELSE` clause might not be best choice. Stick with `WHERE`.

Comment: Can I use both `WHERE` and `ELSE` to help in filtering out the projection that am updating(in case of  hundreds of thousands or millions of records) and to save from entering the values twice respectively?

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to do this would be

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY SET Category_ID = 10 WHERE Category_ID = 2
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY SET Category_ID = 9  WHERE Category_ID = 3
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY SET Category_ID = 12 WHERE Category_ID = 4
UPDATE CustomerDetails_COPY SET Category_ID = 11 WHERE Category_ID = 5
```

Is there any reason you are avoiding this approach?

Is there any correlation between the new and old values of category_ID?

Comment: I have over 300 different types:(

Comment: Why does that change anything? This is a one off query, right? So use your copy/paste feature of your computer and make a day of it. Unless of course the NEW value of any of these conflicts with the OLD value of some. Then you might need a temporary table or Hunter's solution

Comment: Most are different but some are the same.

Comment: Sometimes to deal with php concurrency problem it may have problem for multiple separate SQL Query to execute, since mysql and php are different software, when php execute SQL Query and mysql return the results to php may have a very short delay before execute the next SQL Query. Of coz you can use Transaction to lock the table and execute at once, but some DB Engine just don't support Transaction, Example MyISAM Engine. So i think there is why the question post here for execute them in one query

Answer (score 1):

you could create another table where the mapping is made.. like:

```
map_table
-----------
mani_id
new_id
```

then fill it in...

then

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails_Copy set category_id = (select new_id from map_table where mani_id = category_id )
```