# Update multiple rows with multiple where clauses for each row. (update_batch can only handle 1 where clause)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update my table like this:

```
Update MyTable 
SET value     = 1 
WHERE game_id = 1,
      x       =-4,
      y       = 8

SET value     = 2 
WHERE game_id = 1,
      x       =-3,
      y       = 7

SET value     = 3 
WHERE game_id = 2,
      x       = 5,
      y       = 2
```

I can do a `foreach()` but that will send over 50 separate Queries which is very slow.
That's why I want it to be combined into 1 big Query.

( I do use an **id** for each row but the combination of **game_id**, **x** and **y** is what I use to Identify the row I need. )

The update_batch() function from codeIgniter described here:
[Update batch with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264955/update-batch-with-codeigniter)
was helpful and almost perfect but it only allows for 1 single where clause, you cannot (as far as I understood and tried) enter an array with multiple where clauses.

I've also checked out this question:
[MYSQL UPDATE SET on the Same Column but with multiple WHERE Clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368505/mysql-update-set-on-the-same-column-but-with-multiple-where-clauses)
But it only allows for multiple row updates containing only a single different WHERE clause and I need multiple WHERE clauses! :)

Anwsers can be in simple SQL or with the use of php (and CodeIgniter) or in a different way. I'd this problem to be solved in any possible way ;)

I can really use the advice/help! =D

EDIT:

Sorry the question wasn't clear enough, I just changed it!

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Comment: The anwser is posted here for people who have the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344120/update-multiple-rows-with-multiple-where-clauses-for-each-individual-row

Answer (score 0):

It seems me you need the logical operator `AND`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET value = 1
WHERE game_id = 1
AND x         = -4
AND y         = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the multiple WHERE clauses how you have it laid out, why not just do

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET value     = 1 
WHERE game_id = 1
AND x         = -4
AND y         = 8
```