# Update multiple rows with multiple 'where' clauses for each individual row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update my table like this:

```
Update MyTable 
SET value     = 1 
WHERE game_id = 1,
      x       =-4,
      y       = 8

SET value     = 2 
WHERE game_id = 1,
      x       =-3,
      y       = 7

SET value     = 3 
WHERE game_id = 2,
      x       = 5,
      y       = 2
```

I can do a `foreach()` but that will send over 50 separate Queries which is very slow.
That's why I want it to be combined into 1 big Query.

( I do use an **id** for each row but the combination of **game_id**, **x** and **y** is what I use to Identify the row I need. )

The update_batch() function from codeIgniter described here:
[Update batch with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264955/update-batch-with-codeigniter)
was helpful and almost perfect but it only allows for 1 single where clause, you cannot (as far as I understood and tried) enter an array with multiple where clauses.

I've also checked out this question:
[MYSQL UPDATE SET on the Same Column but with multiple WHERE Clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368505/mysql-update-set-on-the-same-column-but-with-multiple-where-clauses)
But it only allows for multiple row updates containing only a single different WHERE clause and I need multiple WHERE clauses! :)

Anwsers can be in simple SQL or with the use of php (and CodeIgniter) or in a different way. I'd this problem to be solved in any possible way ;)

I can really use the advice/help! =D

Answer (score 52, accepted):

give this a try by using `CASE`

```
Update  MyTable 
SET     value = CASE 
                     WHEN  game_id = 1 AND x = -4 AND y = 8 THEN 1
                     WHEN  game_id = 1 AND x = -3 AND y = 7 THEN 2
                     WHEN  game_id = 2 AND x =  5 AND y = 2 THEN 3
                     ELSE  value 
                END
WHERE   game_ID IN (1,2,3) AND  -- the purpose of this WHERE clause
        x IN (-4, -3, 5) AND    -- is to optimize the query by preventing from
        y IN (8,7,2)            -- performing full table scan.
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll go and try it out now!

Comment: be sure to backup your database first `:D`

Comment: Just wanted to add: if you don't include the last line of `CASE` namely `ELSE value`, then bad things are going to happen. The query will match everything inside the `WHERE` clause and whatever doesn't satisfy any `WHEN` condition will be set to `NULL`