# codeigniter update multiple rows with multiple where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when I try this code:

```
$query = '';
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $where = array(
                'community_id'  => $row->id,
                'user_id'       => $this->session->user_id,
                'status'        => 'invited_to_join',
            );
    $update = array(
                'status' => 'joined',
            );
    $query .= $this->db->set($update)->where($where)->get_compiled_update('community_members').'; ';
}
if ($query)
{   
    return $this->db->query($query);
}
```

it gives me the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE `community_members` SET `status` = 'joined' WHERE
>   `community_id` = '18' A' at line 4

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344247/1235167) uses straightforward query with CASE but I don't know how to convert that into Codeigniter's Query Builder..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this Example;

You can direct use array `$data['id']` like this and no need loop use here as my opine

```
        $this->db->set('status','joined');
        $this->db->where('community_id',$data['id']);
        $this->db->where('user_id',$this->session->user_id); 
        $this->db->where('status','invited_to_join');
        $this->db->update('community_members');
```

Comment: thank you! I knew it has to be very simple.. I wonder why I can't see that the second and third where clause can be joined like that..

Comment: $where = "'community_id'=".$data['id']." AND user_id=".$this->session->user_id." AND status='invited_to_join'";
$this->db->where($where);

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `where` clause this way:

```
    $where = "'community_id'=".$data['id']." AND user_id=".$this->session-user_id." AND status='invited_to_join'";

    $this->db->set('status','joined');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update('community_members');
```

Thank You!!!

Comment: I think your first answer was much better. this method requires manual string escaping..