# MYSQL Update same column with multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368505/mysql-update-set-on-the-same-column-but-with-multiple-where-clauses) question, seems like same as mine. However, there's a little difference between the two as that one is using the same column in where clause and I have a different one.

This is what I'm trying to achieve;

```
UPDATE table 
SET recent = 0 WHERE recent = 1 //update all `recent` column where its value is `1`.
AND
SET recent = 1 WHERE ID = 555 //update specific `recent` column where its ID is `555`.
```

is it possible to do that in one query?

EDIT: The data type of `recent` is `Boolean`, and there should be only one that is set to be `TRUE`. So I want to set it all back to `FALSE` to make sure none of them will be true then update the row with `ID` of `555` to `TRUE` making it the only one `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET    recent = CASE WHEN recent = 1 THEN 0
                     WHEN id = 555   THEN 1
                END
WHERE  recent = 1 OR id = 555
```

Comment: what's the result for a row where recent=1 AND id=555? (And question to the OP: What's the _expected_ outcome in this case?)

Comment: Case is evaluated in order I believe so id = 555 should come first.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of future maintainability: Stop looking for this solution.

What's the implied/expected order?

- Would you first set recent to 0 and then a single item (for 555) to 1?
- Would you set the 555 record to 1, and then (with all the others) back to 0?

I guess I know the answer, but it's easy to miss this in future updates of the code. Optimize for future maintenance, not for saving a statement execution.

Build two statements, execute them within a transaction, and you'll have your readable, maintainable and understandable code.

(even Mureinik's CASE statement does not look that well readable to me, even though I kind of like the solution)